# CSS: Hide Scrollbar.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know how to hide scroll bar. But **without a scroll bar**, I would like to scroll whatever there is to scroll.

This is what I did, it hides initially, and as mouse hovers, vertical scroll bar shows.

```
div#LogoStrip{
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div#LogoStrip:hover{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

But **on hover**, I **don't want to see scrollbar but still would like to scroll the text/images that are present there**, using wheel or two small buttons, 1 at top and 1 at bottom.

```
div#LogoStrip{
        height:600px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

+ `javascript`

can you help with Javascript/jQuery ?

Comment: No plugins. Some reference so that I can build myself.

Comment: As far as I can see it, doing it yourself would be pretty painful. jScrollPane does it by getting rid of the scroll bars altogether and capturing the scroll wheel.

Comment: No Pain, No Gain. Amen! But Seriously, I actually want to learn hard-core JavaScript, not for the language per se, but for 'how to code' learning. And I am fully aware of the fact that jQuery is efficient w.r.t JS, still.

Comment: It's more that this is complex and unstable javascript to work with, it will likely take you quite some time to do it and even then it probably won't be bug free in all browsers.

Comment: Ok Mr @Godwin will look into it. since, I am taking all requests today, what title would you like to see Sir Tomalak ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to code this yourself (and I would again caution against it), you can look through the jScrollPane code. The basic idea is that you have a div within a div, one will hid the contents of the other when set to an offset. You have to capture the scroll wheel event and change that offset.

Comment: See, I never thought of capturing a scroll wheel. It's a start then. though other reason is, I don't want to look into licenses again. I once gave a small exam about various open source licenses and it gave me a head ache. Anyway, will look into it. Any resources you might recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to implement your own custom scroll bar using [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) or another similar plugin.